# Lenovo Mini Wireless Keyboard N5901: Remap orange "My Computer" button

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking, windows-media-center, remote-control, remapping

I have a [Lenovo Mini Wireless Keyboard N5901](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-74153) (a.k.a. Part No. 57Y6336) that I'm using with [my HTPC](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2010/05/htpc-build-part-5-parts-list-my-500.html) running Windows 7.

The remote comes with an orange button in the top-left corner that by default, when pressed, opens the Windows "My Computer" window.  I would like to remap / reprogram this button to act like the green "Windows Media Center" button instead on a Windows Media Center (WMC) remote; that is, open Windows Media Center if it isn't already open, or go to the WMC homepage if WMC is already open.

I've tried several keyboard-remapping utilities (as recommended in other, more general "how to remap keyboard key?" SuperUser.com questions) including SharpKeys, Key Mapper, and KeyTweak, with no luck so far.  None of these utilities recognize the orange button -- they all do recognize that some key was pressed, but display a value for the key of "unsupported" or something similar.

I was able to use a utility called [Keyboard Scan Code Generator](http://www.byremote.com.au/downloads/default.asp?SCLASS=UTILITIES) to determine that a press of the orange button has a KeyData value of 16777217 (0x1000001), and a "Virtual Code" value of 182.  (The other "media" buttons on the N5901 have the same KeyData value, but different Virtual Code values).

I'm not sure at this point where in Windows this keystroke is being interpreted as a command to open "My Computer."  There is no special software / driver for this device; it worked out of the box with Windows 7, no special driver install necessary.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: some other questions have recommended a utility called *Event Ghost* or *EventGhost* to help find troublesome inputs... i think it can also do some automation (a la AutoHotKey).  [SU search](http://superuser.com/search?q=%22eventghost%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it figured out!  The answer from kirk above got me pointed in the right direction.

I'm using this [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
VKB6::  ;On a press of the Lenovo N5901 orange button:
  if WinActive("Windows Media Center")  ;Is WMC the current active window?
    Send #!{Enter}  ;Act like a "green button" press (go to WMC main menu)
  else
    run c:\windows\ehome\ehshell.exe  ;Run/activate WMC
  return
```

This script accomplishes the following on a press of the Lenovo N5901 remote's orange button:

1. If Windows Media Center (WMC) is not running, run it.
2. If WMC is running but is not the active window, activate it.
3. If WMC is the active window, navigate to the WMC main menu.  (As a bonus, a second press of the orange button will return to wherever you were before in WMC.)
4. Suppress the default behavior of bringing up "My Computer" on a press of the orange button.

Essentially, this script turns the N5901's orange button into a standard Windows Media Center remote's "green button."

Credit goes to two sources for components of this script:

(1) The answer from kirk, above, for pointing me towards AutoHotKey in the first place, for the key code to capture a press of the orange button (VBK6), and the means to run/activate WMC (ehshell.exe).

(2) A [post on the AutoHotKey forums by artificeren](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic58359.html) with an AutoHotKey script demonstrating how to conditionally select which action to perform depending on whether or not WMC is the current active window, and how to simulate a key press of the Windows Media Center remote "green button" (navigate to/from the Main Menu in WMC).

Comment: If anyone's interested, I posted my full impressions of the N5901 multimedia remote here: http://blog.jonschneider.com/2010/07/htpc-remote-control-review-lenovo-n5901.html

Answer (score 1):

paste this into an autohotkey script:

VKB6:: run c:\windows\ehome\ehshell.exe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This gets me part of the way towards what I'm trying to do.  The script you suggested does the following on a press of the "orange button": (1) Launches WMC if it isn't already running; (2) Switches to WMC if it is already running; (3) suppresses the old behavior of launching "My Computer".  HOWEVER, it does not cause WMC to go back to its "main menu" when WMC is already running and is the active window.  Any pointers on accomplishing that?

Answer (score 1):

Note for those that want a quick fix for this that doesn't require any 3rd party software:
Open `regedit`, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\17`

Change the `ShellExecute` value from the current value (`::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`, which identifies "My Computer") to whichever app you want to run (ex. notepad).

Keep in mind this will re-map the "My Computer" key on any keyboard (my Dell at work has one, I did this to re-map the WMP key it has to open a cmd prompt).

This works with most of the standard quick launch-type keys.

Comment: Sweet! I'm going to give this a try.